# How to use a smart contract to deploy another smart contract in ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, smart-contract-wallets

Since I have a testing contract with the reentrancy vulnerability, I want to reproduce it. However, only when the deployer is a reentrancy attack contract can this vulnerability be reproduced.
Its codes are as following:

```
contract Forwarder {
  // Address to which any funds sent to this contract will be forwarded
  address public parentAddress;
  event ForwarderDeposited(address from, uint value, bytes data);

  event TokensFlushed(
    address tokenContractAddress, // The contract address of the token
    uint value // Amount of token sent
  );

  /**
   * Create the contract, and set the destination address to that of the creator
   */
  function Forwarder() {
    parentAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * Modifier that will execute internal code block only if the sender is a parent of the forwarder contract
   */
  modifier onlyParent {
    if (msg.sender != parentAddress) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }

  /**
   * Default function; Gets called when Ether is deposited and forwards it to the destination address
   */
  function() payable {
    if (**!parentAddress.call.value(msg.value**)(msg.data))
      throw;
    // Fire off the deposited event if we can forward it  
    ForwarderDeposited(msg.sender, msg.value, msg.data);
  }
}
```

So the first step is using a contract that can exploit the vulnerability to deploy this vulnerable contract,  how can I use a smart contract to deploy another one, especially through Remix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
import './Forwarder.sol';

contract SelfDeploy{
        
    event Addr(address);
    
    function getnewaddress() public returns (uint){
       emit Addr(address(new Forwarder()));
    }
}
```

After the successful transaction, you can check on etherscan or you can put a listener to get the Forwarder's address.